# C++ how to sort vector<class *> with operator <

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

i have

```
 class c1{

public:
    int number;

    c1()
    {
        number=rand()%10;
    }

    bool operator < (c1 *w)
    {
        return number < w->number;
    }


};

vector<c1*> vec = { ... }
sort(vec.begin(),vec.end())
```

why it dosent sort ?

but if we had

```
 bool operator < (c1 w)
    {
        return number < w.number;
    }
```

and

```
vector<c1> vec = { ... }
```

it would have been sorted !

Comment: Sidenote: Assuming that c1 will store more than just an int, you probably do not want to pass your c1 instance by value (as in bool operator < (c1 w)) as this will lead to a copy before comparison. Instead pass the argument by reference (bool operator< (const c1 & w)). Note that this won't fix your original problem (see the other answers), just a general remark.

Comment: Take a look at Pointer Container library from Boost, it seems to provide means working with pointer sequences just like with value sequences.

Answer (score 7):

The most straightforward approach is to define a function

```
bool c1_ptr_less( c1 const *lhs, c1 const *rhs ) {
    return lhs->something < rhs->something;
}

std::sort( vec.begin(), vec.end(), & c1_ptr_less );
```

What I would suggest is a generic functor to take care of *all* pointer arrays

```
struct pointer_less {
    template< typename T >
    bool operator()( T const *lhs, T const *rhs ) const
        { return * lhs < * rhs; }
};

std::sort( vec.begin(), vec.end(), pointer_less() );
```

Armed with this, define the usual `c1::operator< ( const c1 & )` and likewise for other classes.

Generally, best practice is to avoid pointers entirely, including arrays of pointers.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your title question, you can't.

Pointers are built-in types, you cannot override operators where all operands are built-in types.

Luckily, there's an overload of `std::sort` that allows you to specify a comparison function (or functor) so the `operator<` isn't used.

Answer (score 1):

`bool operator < (c1 *w)` compares a `c1` to a `c1 *` - Your sort compares a `c1 *` to a `c1 *`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a compare function to `std::sort`:

```
bool compare_c1 (c1* x, c1* y)
{
  return *x < y;
}

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare_c1);
```

Or if you are using GCC >= 4.5 or Visual Studio 2010 (I'm do not know sure about Intel compiler) you can use lambdas (they are part of the C++0x standard):

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [] (c1* x, c1* y) { return *x < y; });
```

Comment: Did you mean `return *x < *y;` ?

Comment: @Rob Adams, No, topic starter's code contains `c1::operator< (c1*)`, I'm using it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a external operator< and keep de original one:

```
bool operator<(c1* a, c1* b) { return *a < *b; }
```

Now sort will work on the vector.

Comment: As commented in the question, I would change bool operator<(c1) to bool operator<(const c1&) if doing this (assuming that class c1 will store more than just an integer)

Comment: -1: This will not compile.  You cannot define operator overloads where both inputs are primitive types.

Comment: @Oli Just a nit, but a pointer isn't a primitive type.  The rule is that at least one of the types of an overloaded operator must be a class type or an enum type, or a reference to a class type or an enum type.  (But we know what you meant:-).)

Answer (score 0):

phimuemue's answer sums it up, I'll just add that, as a workaround, you can create a wrapper class that contains only one member - a pointer to c1, and then overload its operator <. Then you could sort a vector of object of that class.

Answer (score 0):

And in your example, `vector<c1*>` is sorted.  Just not to the
criteria you seem to want: by default, `sort` uses
`std::less<T>` as the ordering criteria, and `std::less<ci*>`
compares the pointers (which is what you'd expect).  If you
don't want the default criteria, then you have to pass a third
argument to `sort`, a predicate defining the ordering you want.

And of course, your member `operator<(c1*)` will only be called
when you compare a `c1` with a `ci*` (and only if the `c1` is an
rvalue).  Such operators are very, very rare---normally, both
sides of a `<` operator should take the same type (and should be
`const`, since a `<` operator which modifies the values of the
objects it compares would be surprising, to say the least).